# Halt code until button press in another Access form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, error-handling

I have a code snippet that checks if there is an internet connection. If it fails it goes into the error handler and opens a form with some text and a button.

This is a very complex code (not mine).

I want to halt the execution of the code in this function, and to resume it when the button in the other form is pressed.

Internet research has not been helpful. I have no idea how two different code parts could interact.

```vb
On Error GoTo NoConnnectionErrorHandler
    Dim Request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Request.Open "GET", "http://www.bbc.com"
    Request.send
    'MsgBox Request.Status

NoConnnectionErrorHandler:
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm_Global_NoConnectionDialog"
```

When there is no connection to the internet a form opens. How do I stop the code and let it resume when a button in another form is pressed?

It goes through the whole function (where the snippet is only a small part) periodically and checks.
When there is no connection it should halt the whole program, until the button is pressed, and then check the connection again and proceed if there is one.

EDIT: The answer tackles on the problem, but one thing that confuses me is how to trigger the "resume code execution" from a different form via a button press.

Comment: If your form stops the code, **once you close the form** it will automatically hit your `Resume` statement in the answer provided. The form doesn't have to do anything to resume the code execution other than stop it while you resolve your issue. Sorry I can't give you more information as I have zero knowledge on what your form does exactly.

Comment: If you put this in your form to open it, it halts code execution `Me.Show vbModal` if that's what you're asking. `Me` is your userform. [Here is more information on this subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263470%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Oke, thanks mate i will try this out.!

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Alright this seems to work. But another question. How can you resume at a specific line? Microsoft Docs are VERY unspecific and "Resume 1150" does not work it says i need to define a jump marker or something like that

Comment: The same thing you did with `NoConnectionErrorHandler:`. Just name it something else. It makes the code a little sloppy but that’s what it’s asking for. So you can add a line `ResumeFromError1:` or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Ahh oke thanks mate. But man coming from C# VBA is so retarded and backwards ._.

Comment: Lines numbers come from the original BASIC, you have to explicitly write them if you want to use them, and are not directly linked to the effective line counts. They are advantageously replaced by labels.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you should use `Exit Sub` above your error handler (`NoConnectinoErrorHandler`).

Add some code to ensure your error has been resolved, then clear the error and resume your work.

See if this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub foo()

    ' Your unseen code ...

    On Error GoTo NoConnnectionErrorHandler
    Dim Request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Request.Open "GET", "http://www.bbc.com"
    Request.send
    'MsgBox Request.Status


    Exit Sub    'Put this above your error handler
NoConnnectionErrorHandler:
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Frm_Global_NoConnectionDialog"

    'Some code to ensure error no longer exists....

    Err.Clear
    Resume

End Sub
```